# Can't get my javascript to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loading

I have had the desired effects, but have updated the HTML/CSS since, and JS has gone back to zilch.

The fiddle is here -

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/HybridSaiyan/kc285omq/2/).

```js
$( "#allies" ).hover(function() {
  $('body').css("background", "url(https://s24.postimg.org/odj1bt6pf/allies_bg.jpg");
  });
$( "#enemies" ).hover(function() {
  $('body').css("background", "url(https://s24.postimg.org/rzouogd2r/enemies_bg.jpg");
  });  
$( "#fam" ).hover(function() {
$('body').css("background", "url(https://s29.postimg.org/46lataf5x/arch_neutral_cropped.png");
});
```

```css
/*css*/
 
#bg{
  background-image:url('https://s29.postimg.org/46lataf5x/arch_neutral_cropped.png');
}
 
#wrap_main{display:block;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
 
#fam{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  border:double white 30pt;
  width:100%-30pt;
  float:center;
  background-color: black;
  font-family:fantasy, impact;
  font-size:30pt;
  text-align:center;
  padding-bottom:2em;
}
 
#fam img{display:inline-block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
 
#fam a{text-decoration:none;
    color:white;}
 
#fam a:hover{color:gold;}
 
#ae_seg{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
}
 
#allies{
  display:inline-block;
  border:double 30pt;
  background-color:white;
  top:20%;
  width:34%;
  font-family:fantasy, impact;
  font-size:30pt;
}
 
#allies ul li a{text-decoration:none;
    color:black;}
 
#allies ul li a:hover{color:gold;}
 
#enemies{
  display:inline-block;
  border:double rgb(179,33,7) 30pt;
  background-color:white;
  float:right;
  width:34%;
  color:rgb(179,33,7);
  font-family:fantasy, impact;
  font-size:30pt;
}
 
#enemies ul li a{text-decoration:none;
    color:black;}
 
#enemies ul li a:hover{color:gold;}
 
div img{
  width:120px;
  height:70px;
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
 
#footer{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  border:double white 30pt;
  width:100%-30pt;
  float:center;
  background-color:rgb(179,33,7);
}
 
#footer img{height:120px;
}
 
#footer img:hover{
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="bg">
      <div style="padding-bottom:10px;" id="fam">
          <img style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; pagging-top:10px;padding-bottom:40px;" src="http://fontmeme.com/permalink/170208/c2e98ece9088b3589606aa5f59e629f2.png">
          <a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=79788" target="_blank">BBTG_VENG</a><span style="font-size:24pt;color:white;"> & BBTG tags</span>
      </div>
    <div id="wrap_main">
      <div style="padding:4em;">
      </div>
      <div id="ae_seg">
        <div id="allies">
            <img src="http://fontmeme.com/permalink/170203/949c0c2c2c0c34c044b9b45585717a70.png">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=50978" target="_blank">ON HOLIDAY</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=73574" target="_blank">AKD_FLGSHP</a><span style="font-size:24pt;"> & AKD tags</span></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=77265" target="_blank">MOOzing</a><span style="font-size:24pt;"> & Cow related tags</span></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=81836" target="_blank">S N G</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=79535" target="_blank">CRIME CITY</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=59564" target="_blank">BOUTIQUEOG</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=80332" target="_blank">RKNHVK 1</a><span style="font-size:24pt;"> & RKN tags</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="enemies">
            <img src="http://fontmeme.com/permalink/170203/e8d4db59e876e5c94bd8f072137e33e2.png">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=40" target="_blank">PHOENIX</a><span style="font-size:24pt;"> & PHX/PX tags</span></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=42901" target="_blank">THEFALLEN</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=79839" target="_blank">FALLENONES</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=69048" target="_blank">CAULDRON</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=81533" target="_blank">BC TA</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=80207" target="_blank">DIMINISHED2</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.facebook.com/mobwars/family/index.php?family_id=81185" target="_blank">CLF WMD</a><span style="font-size:24pt;"> & WMD tags</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="padding:5.3em;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-bottom:10px;" id="footer">
      <a href="index.htm">
        <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/home-5-xxl.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't see anything wrong with it, but then I'm really not that experienced.

```
$( "#allies" ).hover(function() {
  $('body').css("background", "url(https://s24.postimg.org/odj1bt6pf/allies_bg.jpg");
  });
$( "#enemies" ).hover(function() {
  $('body').css("background", "url(https://s24.postimg.org/rzouogd2r/enemies_bg.jpg");
  });  
$( "#fam" ).hover(function() {
$('body').css("background", "url(https://s29.postimg.org/46lataf5x/arch_neutral_cropped.png");
});
```

Comment: you have no attached jquery.js file that's why it is not working

Comment: That's it, you are using jquery, not plain javascript, so you need to have jquery library attached

Comment: include `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>` and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others already explained it in the comments, your using jQuery and not plain JavaScript. 
You need to attach the jQuery library into your project.

**CDN**
If you want to use jQuery via CDN use following code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

See [jQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/)

**Download**
If you want your own copy of the jQuery library in your project download it [here](https://jquery.com/download/) and implement it like this:

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind, if your using another version of jQuery, you need to change the version number in this snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

I now have this -

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="ae.js"></script>
    <link href="ae.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

but still nothing.

Comment: Can I ask you why you are using an old jQuery version? And do you get any errors in the console? (In your Browser, press F12 and go to the tab Console)

Comment: Oh I had the latest originally, and pasted some other scripts in forgetting to change it back.

I put it right now and console showing no errors. Same story.

Comment: I just noticed that 'ae.js' isn't showing in 'Sources' though.

Comment: Edited name to ae_page and it appeared but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is working now please add `jquery` in your project.
[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kc285omq/4/)

Comment: Did you change something?